# Forecasting using GARCH in R

Tags: r, garch, forecasting

I am using the predict and ugarchforecast functions in R.
When I fit my models and try to forecast, I get either only increasing or decreasing values for sigma, does anyone know why?

Thank you

Example:

eGARCHfit2 = ugarchspec(variance.model=list(model="eGARCH", garchOrder=c(1,1)), mean.model=list(armaOrder=c(0,0), include.mean=TRUE), distribution.model="norm") eGARCH2 <- ugarchfit(brentlog2, spec=eGARCHfit2)

ugarchforecast(eGARCH2, data =brentlog2, n.ahead = 21) 
 * GARCH Model Forecast * ------------------------------------ 
 * Model: eGARCH 
 * Horizon: 21 Roll Steps: 0 Out of Sample: 0 0-roll

forecast [T0=1976-06-26 01:00:00]: 
      Series   Sigma 
T+1 0.0002619  0.008350 
T+2 0.0002619 0.008387 
T+3 0.0002619 0.008423 
T+4 0.0002619 0.008459 
T+5 0.0002619 0.008496 
T+6 0.0002619 0.008532 
T+7 0.0002619 0.008569 
T+8 0.0002619 0.008605 
T+9 0.0002619 0.008642 
T+10 0.0002619 0.008678

The first value is the mean which is always constant and the second one is sigma which is always increasing as you can see.

Comment: Mind to post a simple example?

Comment: Could you please put the comments into the question, the comments are not meant for this.

Comment: Do you ask something new in this question compare to [this one](http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18156/forecasting-using-garch-in-r?lq=1)?

Comment: Hi muffin, no i didnt.
Could you please look at this one if you have time: http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18190/constant-decreasing-volatility-garch-forecasting?noredirect=1#comment26436_18190
Its very similar.
thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This should follow from the properties of the forecast - for example the GARCH(1,1) forecast for $h$ steps is computing the conditional expectation of $\sigma^2_{t+h}$ based on the information set-up in $t$. This can be computed recursively by

$$
V(\varepsilon_{t+h}|F_t)=\omega+\alpha\varepsilon_{t+h-1|F_t}+\beta\sigma^2_{t+h-1|F_t}\\
=\omega\sum\limits_{i=0}^{h-2}(\alpha+\beta)^i+(\alpha+\beta)^{h-1}\sigma^2_{t+1}
$$
something similar but more complicated should hold for the EGARCH model. Stationarity for $\varepsilon_t^2$ hold if $|\alpha+\beta|<1$. If we assume stationarity the second term of the formula above should decrease with $h$. The first term is an increasing function in $h$ for $\omega>0$ which is a standard assumption to ensure the positiveness of the conditional variance. Therefore it seems to me like there is no monotonicity in $h$ but one saddle point at which the forecast starts to increase.

Comment: You're right, thanks! But:

1) how can do I compare this forecasted volatility compared to the realised one if it is always increasing? 

2) how do i extract the realised volatility from a time series?
can i do average of day t+1 / average price of day t for say the volatility at day t+1?

Comment: You're welcome. Basically, what exactly do you mean with 1)? Evaluating predictions does only incorporate your predicted value and the realized one (for example via Diebold-Mariano). I do not see a problem if your long-term predictions only move into one direction. 2)The realized volatility can be extracted for example via intraday data based on e.g. 5 minute intervals. There is a huge literature, I'll refer for example to the literature given in the wikipedia article for Realized variance.

Comment: yh thanks. actually im calculating the realised variance using the first formula here: http://www.volx.us/VolFormula.htm.
But when I fit an ARMA(1,1)-GARCH(1,1), I only get decreasing values for sigma, which is weird. That, i dont get. please refer to my question here:
http://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/18190/constant-decreasing-volatility-garch-forecasting
Thanks a lot!